# finding all empty tables in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

Hi I was wondering how to look for all empty tables in db2. I was thinking of listing all the tables for each schema (i.e "list tables for schema ") and then doing a count(*) query, checking to see which ones give a 0, but this seems cumbersome and dirty since I'd have to write a shell script to parse the table names and loop through each, running the count SQL.

Is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative option is to look at the data dictionary or metadata tables, which will have this information if the appropriate statistics are collected correctly. In oracle, this would be the user/all/dba_tables data dictionary views.

Looks like SYSCAT.TABLES catalog view in D2 serves a similar purpose, but the column value might also have -1, -2 in which case they have different values. Check this link.

[SYSCAT.TABLES catalog view : DB2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0001063.htm)

The count(*) might still be more accurate, since stats gathering in most cases does not guarantee 100% accuracy.

Comment: Although, beware transactions when using `COUNT(*)` - you may get 'old' results.

Comment: Of course. But then, if there are so many transactions going on, the statistics would be stale as well.